# The lyrics of dazz band's Open Sesame

Tags: lyrics, funk

Possibly the most emotional song I've ever heard from Dazz Band's album [*Rock the Room*.](http://philfunk.blogspot.com/2011/06/dazz-band-rock-room-1988-cd.html). I can not find the full lyrics of this song. I just heard something like 'I said "Open Sesame", not I've finally found the key...' at the climax...

Is there someone who happened to got the full lyrics of this song? Or can someone provide me a transcript? Much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a transcript of the lyrics, so I decided to transcribe them myself. There were two lines I couldn't fully figure out, hopefully somebody else would be able to lend a helping hand.

> Ooh wooh wooh
>
> [First Verse]
>   Girl, you're magical, you're mystical
>   You're everything I need.
>   But baby, you've been playing hard to get.
>
> But there's no need to worry,
>   Got a few tricks up my sleeve.
>   And I tell you girl, you ain't seen nothing yet.
>
> But don't think I'm crazy when I say these little words.
>   They're out of a story long ago, I'm sure you've heard:
>
> [Chorus]
>   I said "Open Sesame"
>   Now I've finally found the key.
>   I've been watching you, been wanting you girl,
>   just like [Ali Baba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_Baba).
>
> I said "Open Sesame"
>   Now I've finally found the key.
>   You can't can't resist
>   So open up your heart for me.
>
> [Second Verse]
>   Every day at work I watch you
>   but you never notice me
>   We're so close but yet so far apart (so far away)
>
> So I linger in the shadows,
>   Like a thief does in the night
>   When all I want to do is feel your heart.
>
> Oh I'm so lost out of my head
>   Underneath your spell
>   Your love is like a treasure girl,
>   Straight out of a fairy tail.
>
> [Chorus]
>   I said "Open Sesame"
>   Now I've finally found the key.
>   I've been watching you, been wanting you girl,
>   Just like Ali Baba.
>
> I said "Open Sesame"
>   Now I've finally found the key.
>   I've been watching you, girl, ooh baby
>   just like Ali Baba
>   from a story long time ago
>   I've been watching you (watching you)
>   Waiting on you (waiting for you)
>   Now I've finally found, now I've finally found the key
>   (Open Sesame)
>
> [Guitar Solo]
>
> [Chorus]
>   I said "Open Sesame"
>   Now I've finally found the key.
>   I've been watching you, been wanting you girl
>
> Open Sesame
>   Now I've finally found the key.
>   I've been watching you, been wanting you girl,
>   (Just like Ali Baba)
>
> I said "Open Sesame"
>   Now I've finally found the key.
>   I've been watching you, been wanting you yeah
>
> (Open sesame)
>   Now I've finally found the key.
>   I've been watching you, been wanting you
>   (Just like Ali Baba)
>
> I said "Open Sesame" (You're magical, you're mystical)
>   Now I've finally found the key. (You're everything that I need)
>   I've been watching you, been wanting you yeah (Watching you, wanting you)
>
> Open Sesame (Open sesame)
>   Now I've finally found the key. (Now I've finally found)
>   I've been watching you, been wanting you (wanting you)
>   (Just like Ali Baba)

Comment: Hey it's Just what I need! Thanks a lot man! Keep up the good work...

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy to help

Comment: And I spent loads of time trying to figure out what "Ali barber" means... Ridiculous huh :)

Comment: Hey I've heard this song again and I thought the "???" part could be "Like __a thief does__ in the night"...