# The lyrics of dazz band's Swoop

Tags: lyrics, funk

I can not find the full lyrics for Dazz Band's "Swoop".

Is there someone who happened to got the full lyrics of this song? Or can someone provide me a transcript? Much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the full lyrics either, but [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f35kEWueFwQ) had some of them within the video itself. I transcribed the rest. As with [my answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/3271/431) to [your question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3267/431) about Dazz Band's "Open Sesame", there are a few lines I'm unsure of. Also note that I transcribed the lyrics of shorter version (about 3.5 minutes) of this song, rather than the 8.5 minute 12" version, though I imagine all of these lyrics are simply repeated in that one.

> Ah, swoop!
>
> [First verse]
>   Been giving you the eye
>   By now you realize I want you
>
> Let me have my way
>   I need you not to please you right away
>
> Your smile must find the sun
>   You generate a feel that's on the one
>
> Let's share the things you do
>   There's nothing more important than pleasing you
>
> [Chorus]
>   I'm yours, you got me baby
>   Swoop on it baby (Work it! Swoop!)
>   I'm yours, you got me baby
>   Swoop on it baby (Work it!)
>
> [Second verse]
>   Though looks may be deceiving
>   There're more thing so intriguing 'bout you
>
> You're not one of the needy
>   Waiting for the greedy to swoop
>
> (Swoop!)
>   I'd love to take you in
>   Have you as my lover and your friend
>
> Use me as you're free
>   There'll be no need to see(?), I'm all yours
>   (Heh heh heh heh hey!)
>
> [Chorus x2]
>   I'm yours, you got me baby
>   Swoop on it baby (Work it! Swoop!)
>   I'm yours, you got me baby
>   Swoop on it baby (Work it! Swoop!)
>   I'm yours, you got me baby
>   Swoop on it baby (Work it! Swoop!)
>   I'm yours, you got me baby
>   Swoop on it baby (Work it! Swoop!)
>
> [Bridge]
>   I'm yours as long as you are mine (I'm yours)
>   Baby (baby)
>
> Just let me please you 'cause you're you (You're just one of a kind)
>   Girl!
>
> One thing I want to do, ooh (Gonna share my rest of you)
>
> The time's so right
>   This is our night
>   Let me hold you tight
>   'Cause baby I'm yours!
>
> [Outro]
>   Aw, swoop!
>   Baby!
>   Swoop! (I'm yours!)
>   Baby!
>
> Swoop!
>   Swoop!
>   Swoop!

Comment: Jesus Joe you are a real life saver. respect, bro

Answer (score 0):

Use me as you're free>> **Use me as your freak**<<

There'll be no need to see(?), I'm all yours>>**There'll be no need to sneak, I'm all yours**<<

One thing I want to do, ooh (Gonna share my rest of you)>>**One thing I want to do, ooh (That is share my best with you)**<<